# Selenium Javascript - How to find grandparent and parent

Tags: javascript, selenium

So I have been trying to challange myself and I have been trying to solve grandparent and parent from using `<i class="test-object"></i>` with using the code below

```
<button do-something="" primary-button="" class="gfjhghjfghjfgfh"  disabled="">
<span class="primary-button-wrapper">
  <i class="test-object"></i>
  <span>Nice</span>
</span>
```

Basically what I am trying to be able to do is to find the grapndparent and parent (button and span) using javascript selenium.

So for I have only achieved:

```
 const testing= await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className('test-project'));
 console.log(await testing.getAttribute('class'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options through which you can find the parent of your desired element. For instance

Using JavascriptExecutor:

```
//Find elements by executing client side javascript
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.css(".test-project"));
WebElement parent = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                               "return arguments[0].parentNode;", myElement);
```

Using xpath:

```
//Locate the element you're treating as a child and move up from it using xpath
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.css(".test-project"));
WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
WebElement grandParent = element.findElement(By.xpath("./../.."));
```